# Wich Conditional sounds more natural?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, conditionals

I've learned that we can express "if" by using 「と」,「なら」, by conjugating the verb such as in 「食べる」-> 「食べれば」, and by conjugating in the past and adding 「ら」 such as 「食べる」->「食べたら」. Wich one of this four is more common and/or is used more often? Wich one sounds more natural?

Comment: I know this question has been closed, but you will need to realise that what is most natural depends on the particular context of us. Not just for 'if' but for any particular thing you may wish to say. The fact that you have been taught that all these ways of saying 'if' should naturally imply that each one is a natural expression. What makes them unnatural is being used inapprkpriately. For that, the linked question will hopefully help.

Comment: Thank You for helping even though the question is closed